# PHP array output specific key and/or value

Tags: php, arrays, api, foreach, crm

I want to grab specific values based on keys in my PHP array.

I am getting a whole bunch of unwanted syntax.
I am using this library for API calls to a Insightly CRM https://github.com/Insightly/insightly-php

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<?php
    echo "<h1>PHP Insightly Test</h1>";
    require("insightly.php");
    $i = new Insightly('apikey');
    $contacts = $i->getContacts();
?>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    $array = array(); 
    foreach ($contacts as $contact)
    {
        $array[] = $contact;
    }
    print_r($array[1]);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Webpage output as follows:**

`stdClass Object ( [CONTACT_ID] => 1234567 [SALUTATION] => [FIRST_NAME] => Frank [LAST_NAME] => Foster [BACKGROUND] => [IMAGE_URL] => http://dfvd [DEFAULT_LINKED_ORGANISATION] => [OWNER_USER_ID] => 343435 [DATE_CREATED_UTC] => 2015-11-22 21:46:25 [DATE_UPDATED_UTC] => 2015-11-22 21:52:19 [VISIBLE_TO] => EVERYONE [VISIBLE_TEAM_ID] => [VISIBLE_USER_IDS] => [CUSTOMFIELDS] => Array ( ) [ADDRESSES] => Array ( ) [CONTACTINFOS] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [CONTACT_INFO_ID] => 34353453 [TYPE] => EMAIL [SUBTYPE] => [LABEL] => Work [DETAIL] => email@email.com ) ) [DATES] => Array ( ) [TAGS] => Array ( ) [LINKS] => Array ( ) [CONTACTLINKS] => Array ( ) [EMAILLINKS] => Array ( ) )`

I require individual values

e.g (first name / last name) - Frank Foster

I tried `print_r($array[1]['FIRST_NAME']);`? but had no luck. Wondering if I need to encode or decode? Unsure the answer to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can echo FIRST_NAME using this Syntax:

```
echo $array[1]->FIRST_NAME;
```

Comment: Please vote up answers also, It helps us a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use should use "->" to access object properties.

```
print_r($array[1]->FIRST_NAME);
```